# ajax equivalent to this curl command

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have had some issues with this and need a solution I have this curl command

```
curl -d data1='Some String' -d data2='some string' http://somesite.com/path/is/here
```

what would that look like using a jquery ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data like that:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/some_url',
  data: { first: "some string", second: "some string" }
});
```

For full options of ajax call with jQuery, please refer the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

It will look like this:

```
 $.ajax({
       url: 'http://somesite.com/path/is/here',
       type: 'GET',   // or POST
       data: {
                data1: 'Some String',
                data2: 'some string'
              },
       success: function(data) {
                // do something
               },
       error: function(error) {
                 // handle error
               }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the webserver on somesite.com must allow Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS), otherwise your webbrowser will prevent any such Ajax calls because of the Same-origin policy (SOP).